# How to write Cassandra query with discontinuous values for a column in the where clause

Tags: cassandra, nosql, datastax, cassandra-3.0

I have a time series data of power_drawl at 1 minute interval for several years. That is each day will have 1440 (60min * 24hr) values.

This is my table,

```
CREATE TABLE power_drawl (date date, time time, x_power_mw float, PRIMARY KEY(date, time)) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (time ASC); 




SELECT * FROM power_drawl WHERE date='2016-01-01' and time>='00:00:00' and time<='00:10:00' ALLOW FILTERING ;   

 date       | time               | x_power_mw
------------+--------------------+--------------------------------
 2016-01-01 | 00:00:00.000000000 |                          23.95
 2016-01-01 | 00:01:00.000000000 |                          24.17
 2016-01-01 | 00:02:00.000000000 |                          23.52
 2016-01-01 | 00:03:00.000000000 |                          21.17
 2016-01-01 | 00:04:00.000000000 |                          24.53
 2016-01-01 | 00:05:00.000000000 |                          25.06
 2016-01-01 | 00:06:00.000000000 |                           28.5
 2016-01-01 | 00:07:00.000000000 |                          25.52
 2016-01-01 | 00:08:00.000000000 |                          25.66
 2016-01-01 | 00:09:00.000000000 |                           25.4
 2016-01-01 | 00:10:00.000000000 |                          23.25
```

Now I have a query like this
"what is the `max` value of `x_power_mw` between 12 pm to 2 pm every day in the month of january in the year 2011 to 2015 and when did it occurred"
"And in the above query what if I want query for year 2011 and 2015 rather than 2011 to 2015 (discontinuous values)"

For me it seems that it is impossible to write a single `cql` query for these queries.
1) How to write a `cql` query with `where` clause having year 2011 and 2015 rather than 2011 to 2015?

2) Is it a good idea to query separately for each year and compute the maximum at client side?

3) Is my `data model`  correct for these queries, if not which is the correct (should I separate year from the date to add as a composite clustering key )?

Answer (score 0):

1. Because in your case you have a `date` as a partition key, you need to generate all possible values for all days in january in 2011-2015, and execute queries in the parallel (**it's not recommended to use `IN` on the partition key** as it will overload the coordinating node). In your case you'll get 155 queries to execute.
2. You can use `max` in your query to perform to find given value, although it will be more tricky to get associated timestamp (maybe you can use user-defined function to return a tuple of max/timestamp). But it's ok to perform filtering on the client side, as you transfer only 120 values (1 per minute).
3. Theoretically you can use year as partition key and use `timestamp` instead of `time` for clustering column, but in this case you'll get ~0.5 million cells per partition that is above recommended max value of 100k/partition. You can still use date, but truncate it to the month, so you'll get ~45k cells per partition, and continue to use `timestamp` as clustering column. But it may not help with selection of only specific ranges inside every day.